# Dynamic Mapping Templates seem to prevent mappings from being created

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to index some data with dynamic user-created fields.  The input data looks like this:

```
{ "kind": "feature",
  "creationDate": 1424561126000,
  "key" : "sdfgsdfg",
  "user": {
    "email" : "me@example.com",
    "custom": {
      "hello": "world",
      "answer": 42,
      "enable_the_thing": true
    }
  }
}
```

The keys and values in the `user.custom` object are dynamic, and it is even possible that some instances will have values of different types for the same key.  So, I am translating these into a shape like this:

```
    "custom": {
      "hello": {
        "stringVal": "world"
      },
      "answer": {
        "numVal": 42
      },
      "enable_the_thing": {
        "boolVal": true
      }
    }
```

(This way, I can be sure that `user.custom.hello.stringVal` will always be a string, even if another document has a numeric `user.custom.hello.numVal`.)

So far, this seems to work.  I declared the mapping for `user.custom` as:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "dynamic": true
}
```

When I get the mapping, I see these dynamic fields are created as I expect.

However, I also need to keep an unanalyzed string representation of all of these values.  So, I added a dynamic mapping template like this (and one for the `numVal` and `boolVal` fields as well):

```
"custom_attribute_string": {
    "mapping": {
        "fields": {
            "stringVal": {
                "index": "analyzed", 
                "type": "string"
            }, 
            "untouched": {
                "index": "not_analyzed", 
                "type": "string"
            }
        }, 
        "type": "multi_field"
    }, 
    "path_match": "user.custom.*.stringVal"
}
```

However, now the dynamic custom fields are not created in the mapping, and the documents are not indexed.

I suspect there is something wrong with my mapping template, but I'm not sure where to look.  I created this template based on these [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates), but maybe I should be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Your dynamic mapping works perfectly, the `untouched` field is created but it won't show up in your results when viewing the source of your document. `_source` will only ever contain whatever data you sent for indexing. Elasticsearch will index each field according to the mapping you've specified, but it won't modify the `_source`

You can see that the `untouched` sub-field does indeed exist by running an aggregation on it:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "untouched_values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.custom.hello.stringVal.untouched"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a side-note, the `multi-field` type has been deprecated a while ago, so even though it still works, you should use the new way of specifying multi-fields instead, like this:

```
"custom_attribute_string": {
    "mapping": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
            "untouched": {
                "index": "not_analyzed", 
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "path_match": "user.custom.*.stringVal"
}
```

Note that in order to recreate your issue above, I've created the following index:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/testindex -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "custom_attribute_string": {
            "mapping": {
              "fields": {
                "stringVal": {
                  "index": "analyzed",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "untouched": {
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "type": "multi_field"
            },
            "path_match": "user.custom.*.stringVal"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "properties": {
            "email": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "custom": {
              "type": "object",
              "dynamic": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And then I indexed the following test document:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/testindex/test/1 -d '{
  "user": {
    "email": "val@me.com",
    "custom": {
      "hello": {
        "stringVal": "world"
      },
      "answer": {
        "numVal": 42
      },
      "enable_the_thing": {
        "boolVal": true
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

After running this, I retrieved the mapping and as you can see the `hello.stringVal.untouched` sub-field is present:

```
{
  "customs" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "custom" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "custom_attribute_string" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "multi_field",
              "fields" : {
                "untouched" : {
                  "index" : "not_analyzed",
                  "type" : "string"
                },
                "stringVal" : {
                  "index" : "analyzed",
                  "type" : "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "path_match" : "user.custom.*.stringVal"
          }
        } ],
        "properties" : {
          "user" : {
            "properties" : {
              "custom" : {
                "dynamic" : "true",
                "properties" : {
                  "answer" : {
                    "dynamic" : "true",
                    "properties" : {
                      "numVal" : {
                        "type" : "long"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "enable_the_thing" : {
                    "dynamic" : "true",
                    "properties" : {
                      "boolVal" : {
                        "type" : "boolean"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "hello" : {
                    "dynamic" : "true",
                    "properties" : {
                      "stringVal" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "fields" : {
                          "untouched" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "index" : "not_analyzed"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "email" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. When I tried to get the mapping after inserting some documents, I did not see the mappings created for the dynamic fields. More importantly, I also did not see the documents in the index at all, so I'm guessing there was something in the mapping & document that was incompatible.  I ended up swapping my three dynamic templates for a single template for an object with three fields (`stringVal`, `boolVal` and `numVal`), and using that with a `path_match` on `user.custom.*`.

Comment: Normally, ES would always index something even if the mappings don't match. How did you index your documents and how did you retrieve them?

Comment: I indexed them using the elastigo library, and I was (trying to) retrieve them using the head plugin, on the browser tab (this index is empty except for the test document I was trying to insert).

Comment: Also, I did not get any error when inserting, but I have some suspicions that elastigo sometimes swallows errors when it should not.  I have, however, seen errors when inserting a document with fields of an incompatible type compared to the mapping (ie, a numeric value in a boolean field).  That is what led me to do the whole `stringVal`/`boolVal`/etc thing.

Comment: My advice is that when crafting mappings, always go with bare hands first by using curl or Sense and when all works, you can go through libraries for indexing your data. Principle of least surprise!